# python acknowlage in pushover using dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, pushover

I'm having trouble trying too get an acknowledgement from pushover using python.

In my script I'm using a dict to send the same message to 2 people and record once the message has been acknowledged.
The reason I'm doing it this way and not in a group is because if one person acknowledges then it cancels the call for rest so if one person sees it and acknowledges and another doesn't then the alert stops for the group.

So far my code will send the message for both uid but will not print once they have acknowledged

```
import time
import requests
import datetime
dict = {'u56pt7jQXxgmtGnX5MBgsnUz4kgqKS': 'User1', 'uoREW3cuvy3SbSnyc7Ra737nVbrBQh': 'user2'}
app = "app id"
for k in dict:
        user = k
        params = {
        'token': app,
        'user': user,
        'title': 'lala',
        'message': 'test',
        'retry': 300, 
        'expire': 40,
        'priority': 2 ,
        'sound': 'siren',
        }
        msg = requests.post('https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json', data=params)
        print "POSTed message to " + k
        json_data = msg.json()
        print json_data['receipt']
        time.sleep(5)
        d = json_data['receipt']
        v = requests.get("https://api.pushover.net/1/receipts/"+ d + ".json?token=" + app)
        out = v.json()
while out['acknowledged'] is 0:
 print "not yet" #placed for debugging
 time.sleep(5)
 v = requests.get("https://api.pushover.net/1/receipts/"+ d + ".json?token=" + app)
if out['acknowledged'] is 1:
 ack = out['acknowledged_by']
 for k in dict:
  if ack in k:
   acked = dict[k]
   t = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%H:%M')
   print (acked + " acknowledged at " + t)
```

UPDATE

Using code provided below this now recheck the while statement but still only acknowledges the second dict entry.

Looking over the code I believe the

```
v = requests.get("https://api.pushover.net/1/receipts/"+ d + ".json?token=" + app)
```

is only checking the second dict entry not both.

Comment: Can we see what a sample `dict` looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first test loop

```
while out['acknowledged'] is 0:
    print "not yet" #placed for debugging
    time.sleep(5)
    v = requests.get("https://api.pushover.net/1/receipts/"+ d + ".json?token=" + app)
    out = v.json() #update the out, so you can check again
```

And in the second part you will need to convert it into a loop that terminates after everyone has made an acknowledgement

```
if out['acknowledged'] is 1:
    while not all_acknowledged(dict): # custom function to check whether all users have made an acknowledgement 
        ack = out['acknowledged_by']
        for k in dict:
            if ack in k:
                acked = dict[k]
                dict[k]['ack'] = True #We must update this when we come across an acknowledged user
                t = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%H:%M')
                print (acked + " acknowledged at " + t)
        v = requests.get("https://api.pushover.net/1/receipts/"+ d + ".json?token=" + app)
        out = v.json() #update the out, so you can check again
```

To collect everyones acknowledgement you will need either an additional entry in your dict for each user that holds whether that user acknowledges or another data structure to keep track of all acknowledgements (for arbitrary many users).

```
for k in dict:
    user = k
    params = {
    'token': app,
    'user': user,
    'title': 'lala',
    'message': 'test',
    'retry': 300, 
    'expire': 40,
    'priority': 2 ,
    'sound': 'siren',
    'ack': False
    }
```

Once we add the `ack` field we can update it in our second loop and create the function, so

```
def all_acknowledged(dict):
    for k in dict:
        if not dict[k]['ack']:
            return False
    return True
```

So, in the end we will have this:

```
import time
import requests
import datetime
dict = {'u56pt7jQXxgmtGnX5MBgsnUz4kgqKS': 'User1', 'uoREW3cuvy3SbSnyc7Ra737nVbrBQh': 'user2'}
app = "app id"
for k in dict:
    user = k
    params = {
    'token': app,
    'user': user,
    'title': 'lala',
    'message': 'test',
    'retry': 300, 
    'expire': 40,
    'priority': 2 ,
    'sound': 'siren',
    'ack': False
    }
    msg = requests.post('https://api.pushover.net/1/messages.json', data=params)
    print "POSTed message to " + dict[k]
    json_data = msg.json()
    print json_data['receipt']
    time.sleep(5)
    d = json_data['receipt']
    v = requests.get("https://api.pushover.net/1/receipts/"+ d + ".json?token=" + app)
    out = v.json()
while out['acknowledged'] is 0:
    print "not yet" #placed for debugging
    time.sleep(5)
    v = requests.get("https://api.pushover.net/1/receipts/"+ d + ".json?token=" + app)
    out = v.json() #update the out, so you can check again

def all_acknowledged(dict):
    for user in params:
        if not params['ack']:
            return False
    return True

# Line below is commented out because if we got this far we have at least one acknowledgement 
# if out['acknowledged'] is 1: 
while not all_acknowledged(dict): # custom function to check whether all users have made an acknowledgement 
    ack = out['acknowledged_by']
    for k in dict:
        if ack in k:
            acked = dict[k]
            params['ack'] = True # We must update this when we come across an acknowledged user
            t = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%H:%M')
            print (acked + " acknowledged at " + t)
    v = requests.get("https://api.pushover.net/1/receipts/"+ d + ".json?token=" + app)
    out = v.json() #update the out, so you can check again
```

Comment: Great half way there. yeah i didn't stop to think of that. please read update

Comment: Any ideas on how we could achive this ?

Comment: The answer above should work. Notice that even the second loop is updated.

Comment: So that second loop is place after the while loop?

Comment: I combined all the code, you should check it over and see if its correct.

Comment: Gets an error at  `if not dict[k]['ack']` being *string indices must be integers not str*. So I looked at code and `'ack' `is not in the dict thats called its in prams so will this line need to change to look in prams not dict?

Comment: I cannot test the code, but it should work. Make sure to copy the new `dict` for loop from the top.

Comment: Yeah i did that and get error listed. As stated `dict` dosnt have `ack` in it but its called in `prams`  so does it have to be called from there?

Comment: Ah! Yes you are correct. `dict[k]['params']['ack']` should work.

Comment: Werid same message?  Thinking out aloud. If `params` is its own dict in a way (layout) calling it from `dict` wont work as `params` is not in `dict` but `dict` is in `params` by calling `k`?

Comment: Got it working see sugested edit of your post. Will test with more than one uid later.